# Swing: format in JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, format, textarea

I am using the below code to a button to copy the contents of the text area created using Java Swing to a text file (along with other fields on the application).

```
File dir= new File("C:\\Siner");
if (!dir.exists()) dir.mkdir();
else {}
//Date datetime=new Date();
SimpleDateFormat form = new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm-ss_a_zzz");
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("C:\\Siner\\"+converse+"_" +form.format(date)+ ".txt");
PrintWriter pw;
pw = new PrintWriter(writer);
pw.println(get);
pw.close();
```

Issue: Let's say the data on the text area that has 15 lines. So when I use the button to create a text file 15 lines data will be formatted to 4 or 5 lines. I used word wrap but that didn't help.

How do I make sure I retain the same format available in Text Area?

Comment: If line/word wrapping is enabled, this is a constraint of the view, not the data, so there really isn't much you can do, without making it very, very complicated

Comment: @MadProgrammer No word wrapping is not enabled. Also, the button which creates a text file also copies the contents to the clipboard. So if i manually copy to notepad the format looks good. The problem is only when the file is created and contents change formats.

Comment: Consider providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), including your input, expected and actual output

Comment: And because I'm lazy, you might also like to have a look at [`JTextComponent#write`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#write-java.io.Writer-)